# When rendering a model, how to use a blade template instead of json as default?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Is it possible to assign a blade template to a model?

Instead of doing this:

```
@php $contact = Contact::find(1); @endphp
@include('contact', ['contact' => $contact])
```

I'd like to just do:

```
@php $contact = Contact::find(1); @endphp
{{ $contact }}
```

But latter obviously just spits out the model in json.

Comment: Why not just create a [Blade component](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components) and pass the `$contact` as a parameter?

Comment: @Peppermintology well thats what I do, I just wonder if its possible to assign a template for a model type as default. I think its more elegant that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with PHP's `__toString()` magic method: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Let's make an example for default `User.php` model.

First, create a blade file for that model, lets create that as `/resources/views/model/user.blade.php` and a dummy component;

```
<h1>{{ $user->name }}</h1>
<p>{{ $user->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
```

Now make this default `__toString()` for `User` model.

Add this to `app/Models/User.php` ;

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString(): string
{
    return view('model.user', ['user' => $this])->render();
}
```

Now you can test it directly in your `routes/web.php` ;

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    echo \App\Models\User::first();
});
```

Or try to echo it in any view as;

```
{!! $user !!}
```

You can't use `{{ $user }}` because you need that HTML tags, so you have to use it as `{!! $user !!}`

Comment: ah, that makes sense. thanks a lot

Comment: Just for completeness: `__toString()` must return a string so you have to return `view()->render();`